# How to get Magento 2 events in the order of execution for debugging?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

By the way, I hope you won't judge the roughness of this answer, just something quick I wanted to get out there :)

How would I be able to log all events magento dispatches in the order of execution?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault::dispatch

```
public function dispatch(array $configuration, Observer $observer)
        {
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($observer
                ->getEvent()->getName());
```

Comment: I have tried the above code..with if($observer->getEvent()->getName() == "sales_model_service_quote_submit_success"){
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($observer->getName());
        } . but observer name seems to be empty.

Comment: You are using "$observer->getName()‌​", try getting the event: $observer->getEvent()->getName()

Comment: $observer->getEvent()->getName()  gives me event name. but need the observer names of that particular event.

Comment: Try this (new ReflectionClass($observer))->getProperties() and see what's inside the observer. I must note, I haven't worked with magento for a while, asking a coworker (if you are working) might be more productive :D If that doesn't work, I'm not sure about this ... just a wild guess I think the event might hold the observer you want, thus $observer->getEvent()->getObserver()->getName()... just guessing

Comment: Also if you have the event name, you can check all the observers by running a search on your project files, use the event name as the search query and put a var_dump into the observers codes.
Example event declaration in events.xml 
<event name="my_module_event_before">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>